# Solr возвращает вместе с корректными данным излишние данные

Tags: java, полнотекстовый-поиск, solr

У меня есть `Spring MVC` проект. К нему прикручен `Solr`. В приложении есть возможность поиска работников(через `Solr`). Поиск работает по большей части корректно, можно найти пользователя с именем Иван введя соответственно **Иван**, либо не переключая англ. раскладку **Bdfy**. Пользователь выведется без проблем. Но существуют пользователи, при выводе которых одновременно выводятся и не подходящие по запросу пользователи. Например, если ввести **Абдула**, выведется сам **Абдула**, а так же несколько неподходящих пользователей. Вот пример с фронта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```java
public <T extends Index> IndexQueryResult<T> query(IndexQuery<T> indexQuery) throws IndexException {
        Core core = getCore(indexQuery.getEntityClass());
        try {
            if (core == null)
                throw new SolrServerException("Solr core is not defined");

            SolrClient solr = solrConfiguration.getSolrClient(core);

            String selectQuery = indexQuery.getQuery() == null
                    ? "" : StringUtils.escapeCharacters(indexQuery.getQuery(), ESCAPE_CHARACTERS, '\\');
            String spellcheckSuggestion = null;
            if (indexQuery.isUseSpellcheck()) {
                SolrQuery spellSelect = new SolrQuery(selectQuery);
                spellSelect.setParam("spellcheck.q", selectQuery);
                spellSelect.setParam("spellcheck", "on");
                spellSelect.setRequestHandler("/spell");
                QueryResponse spellResponse = solr.query(spellSelect, SolrRequest.METHOD.POST);
                if (spellResponse.getSpellCheckResponse() != null) {
                    spellcheckSuggestion = spellResponse.getSpellCheckResponse().getCollatedResult();
                }
            }

// Other method code ...

}
```

Configs:

```xml
  <requestHandler name="/spell" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="df">text_spell</str>
      <!-- Solr will use suggestions from both the 'default' spellchecker
           and from the 'wordbreak' spellchecker and combine them.
           collations (re-written queries) can include a combination of
           corrections from both spellcheckers -->
      <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">default</str>
<!--      <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">wordbreak</str>-->
      <str name="spellcheck">on</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.extendedResults">true</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.count">10</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.alternativeTermCount">0</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.maxResultsForSuggest">0</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.collate">true</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.collateExtendedResults">true</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.maxCollationTries">10</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.maxCollations">5</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="last-components">
      <str>spellcheck</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>
```

Мой метод который преобразует слово исходя из одной раскладки в другую раскладку клавиатуры:

```java
protected static final char[] LATINS = {'q', 'w', 'e', 'r', 't', 'y', 'u', 'i', 'o', 'p', '[', ']',
            'a', 's', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', ';', '\'', 'z', 'x', 'c', 'v',
            'b', 'n', 'm', ',', '.', '`'};

// ... other code

protected void incrementTokenLogic() {
        char[] buffer = charTermAttr.buffer();
        if (buffer.length > 0) {
            char[] newBuffer = new char[charTermAttr.length()];
            for (int i = 0; i < charTermAttr.length(); i++) {
                char ch = buffer[i];
                if (LATIN_TO_CYR_MAP.containsKey(ch)) {
                    newBuffer[i] = LATIN_TO_CYR_MAP.get(ch);
                } else {
                    newBuffer[i] = CYR_TO_LATIN_MAP.getOrDefault(ch, ch);
                }
            }
            terms.add(newBuffer);
        }
    }
```

Проблема в том, что помимо того, что `Solr` выводит корректного пользователя, затем он берет слово "**Абдула**", переводит его на раскладку ENG -> **F,lekf**, и исходя из этого слова возвращает ненужных пользователей, которые не подходят. Из-за знака препинания, которое встречается в **F,lekf**.

Что можно в связи с этим предпринять?

Comment: Как минимум, можно в `incrementTokenLogic` игнорировать результат конверсии RU->ENG, если в нём присустствуют символы `[]{};:'",<.>/?`. Как максимум - потренировать нейронную сеть на распознавание распространенных последовательностей символов в реальных фамилиях. Средний вариант - сделать модель на базе марковской цепи для русских и английских фамилий. Однако, я считаю что эвристика по недопустимым символам сработает достаточно хорошо.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше всего сделать как предложил [Pak Uula](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/371023/pak-uula) - не добавлять к поисковым термам результаты конвертирования, если там есть что-либо кроме букв.

Другой вариант, который полезно знать: можно настроить query `analyzer` для того типа поля, которое вы используете для имени, чтобы он считал запятую алфавитно-цифровым символом и соответсвенно не токенизировал запросы с запятой.

Делается это так. Главное это добавить `WordDelimiterFilterFactory` в `analyzer` с типом `query`:

```
    <fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
          <!-- ... пропускаю -->
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
                generateWordParts="1"
                generateNumberParts="1" 
                catenateWords="1" 
                catenateNumbers="1" 
                catenateAll="0" 
                splitOnCaseChange="1"
                types="wdftypes.txt"/>
        <!-- ... тут еще могут быть фильтры -->
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

Ключевой момент тут это `types="wdftypes.txt"`, остальные настройки смотрите под себя, тут я не знаю ваших остальных требований. `wdftypes.txt` это файл, в вашем случае такого вида:

```
, => ALPHANUM
```

Т.е. он указывает, что запятую считаем буквой. Его нужно положить в каталог `conf`.